# How to make state dependent on other state in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My use case is rather specific, but basically, I will often get a list of objects that have IDs that I need to match to a list of objects the application has saved that has the same IDs. I need to often find the intersection of these two lists to present them to the user, and this "intersectionList" needs to be state in a View Model.

It's not difficult to find the intersection of these two lists based on the ID field, however I don't know how to place this variable in a View Model.

For example:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val newObjects = ServiceSingleton.newObjects.asStateFlow()
    val savedObjects = DataSingleton.savedObjects.asStateFlow()

    private val _intersectionObjects = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Object>())
    val intersectionObjects = _intersectionObjects.asStateFlow()
}
```

I need the `_intersectionObjects` to always be the intersection of `newObjects` and `savedObjects` and to update whenever either of those lists are updated, so that in my composable I can do:

```
...
val objectsToShow by viewModel.intersectionObjects.collectAsStateWithLifeCycle()
...
```

This does not work:

```
// ViewModel
val newObjects = ServiceSingleton.newObjects.asStateFlow()

private val _intersectionObjects = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Object>())
    get() {
        val setOfSavedObjectIds = DataSingleton.setOfIds
        val intersection = newObjects.value.filter {
            it.id !in setOfSavedObjectIds
        }
        return MutableStateFlow(intersection)
    }
val intersectionObjects = _intersectionObjects.asStateFlow()
```

because the `intersectionObjects` isn't actually propagating updates to the UI.

This does work:

```
// ViewModel
val newObjects = ServiceSingleton.newObjects.asStateFlow()

fun getIntersectionObjects(newObjects: List<Objects>): List<Objects> {
    val setOfSavedObjectIds = DataSingleton.setOfIds
    return newObjects.filter {
        it.id !in setOfSavedObjetIds
    }
}
```

```
// Composable
...
val newObjects by viewModel.newObjects.collectAsStateWithLifeCycle()
val objectsToShow = viewModel.getIntersectionObjects(newObjects)
...
```

because the `newObjects` variable in the UI is actually receiving updates, causing the composable to recompose, however it's not the actual data I want and I don't think it should be in the UI. Essentially, I don't think this is the best way to go about it, but I don't know how else to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) to combine multiple flows:

```kotlin
val newObjects = ServiceSingleton.newObjects.asStateFlow()
val savedObjects = DataSingleton.savedObjects.asStateFlow()

val intersectionObjects = combine(newObjects, savedObjects) { new, saved ->
    intersection(new, saved) // your implementation of intersection
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())
```

From the documentation:

> Returns a `Flow` whose values are generated with `transform` function by combining the most recently emitted values by each flow.